# Setting value via variable in apache httpd.conf

Tags: apache-2.4, httpd.conf, regex

I have the following entry in my apache config file:

```
<LocationMatch "/hls-vod/(?<id>[0-9][0-9])/(.*)">
HLSHttpStreamingEnabled true
HLSMediaFileDuration 8000
HttpStreamingContentPath    "${VIDEO_ROOT}/%{env:MATCH_id}"
HLSFmsDirPath ".."
HLSJITConfAllowed true
HLSAMFToId3MappingFilePath conf/AMF_to_Id3_Mapping.xml
```

The issue is that that with this in place apache won't start - it immediately crashes. I remove %{env:MATCH_id} it loads.

As far as I can tell from the apache docs though that should be valid. So I'm not sure why its dying. Can anyone help?

Apache Docs:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#locationmatch

Thanks!

Comment: The doc states "environment with the corresponding name prefixed with "MATCH_" and in upper case." So perhaps it must be `MATCH_ID` instead? Furthermore the documentation refers to `LocationMatch` and says nothing about `HttpStreamingContentPath` which may or may not allow these environment variables?

Comment: @Tommiie I tried with ID upper and lower case. I also tried using something other than ID in case that was a reserved word. That didn't help. I don't know how to tell if HTTPStreamingContentPath does or doesn't allow environment variables but I was under the impression that environment variables could be used anywhere.

Comment: @Tommiie furthermore it supports ${VIDEO_ROOT} so...?

Comment: `${VIDEO_ROOT}` is not an environment variable. Either way I'm not that familiar with environment variables so I wouldn't know whether they are allowed anywhere or not.

Comment: Also, what is `%{env:MATCH_ID}` supposed to contain?

Comment: @Tommiie a number 00-99 which is passed via the URL. So the requesting url looks like http://www.example.com/hls-vod/11/filename.ext.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by enabling urlrewrite:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
RewriteEngine On
```

Then in the  block using this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^/hls-vod/(.*) /$1 [R,NC,L]
```

Hope this helps someone else.